# script errors in IE

Tags: javascript, browser, encoding, extjs, internet-explorer-9

I work on **extjs-based** (v 3.4) website. At Firefox, Safari and Chrome it runs well. But when I try to use Internet Explorer 9 I always get strange errors:

```
SCRIPT5009: 'п»ї' is undefined 
ext-lang-ru.js, line 7 character 1

SCRIPT87: Invalid argument. 
ext-all.js, line 7 character 90121
```

I tried to save my files in different encodings, but it didn't help. Maybe anyone else had already faced such problem?

Comment: The first error looks like an UTF8 BOM (byte order mark) - try to remove it or save without BOM.

Comment: But ext-all.js file is already saved in ANSI encoding and ext-lang-ru.js is saved in UTF-8 without BOM

Comment: Have you got a link to the files in question?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the charset-attribute of the script-file:

```
<script src="path/to/ext-lang-ru.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```